# transform ISO date from JSON to date Object in java

Tags: java, json

I am getting this `"createdAt":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2013-05-04T16:24:42.701Z"}` as part of JSON from my backend. How can I convert it to Java Date object. in pseudo: 
`Date d = ISODateFromJSONToJavaDate(jsonObj);`

**progress:**
is there any way to format iso type date String to java date?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the GMT timezone, what if it is not GMT? Are zones displayed as, say, `+01:00` or `GMT+1`? Also, do you have a JSON parser yet?

Comment: no I don't have it yet but I think i would use Gson

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a library - Joda Time might be a good candidate for handling this.

The other option is to build a SimpleDateFormat using a matching format string.